# How to superimpose matrix values around scatter points in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

You can find the matrix [here](https://github.com/Slothfulwave612/data/blob/master/misc/matrix.py).

I am using `imshow()` method to superimpose the matrix value over a plot, which has two scatter points. Python code is listed below:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,12))
ax.axis("off")

ax.scatter(
    62, 50, fc="gold", ec="#000000", s=300, zorder=3, lw=1.5
)
ax.scatter(
    70.5, 23, fc="cornflowerblue", ec="#000000", s=300, zorder=3, lw=1.5
)


ax.imshow(
    matrix, extent=(0, 105, 0, 68), cmap="bwr", interpolation="gaussian", vmin=0, vmax=1
)
```

The above code is giving me the following output:-
[image]

So the thing here is the values are superimposed over the whole plot, but what I want is to get color only around the yellow and blue dot, something like this:

[image]

The above image has been edited using image-editor. So I want the above output where the values(or colors) are only shown around the scatter-points not the whole plot.

How can I implement this with matplotlib?